# Using gstreamer with openvino opencv in rpi4 without installing gstreamer packages

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, openvino

I am trying to use gstreamer pipeline with openvino opencv-4.1. I don't have the root permission so can't install any packages. So I copied all the needed libs for gstreamer into /usr/local/lib. But when I am using the pipeline using cv::cap.open() with CAP_GSTREAMER, the pipeline isn't working and also not showing any error. But if I try the same pipeline with gst-launce-1.0 it is working fine.

I couldn't find any missing libs also. It will be great help if anyone can help me on this. Any help regarding making it working or a way to show the error for which its not working will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.